# RSA: If the least significant bits of the factors are leaked, what advantage is there in factoring N?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

For $N=pq$, if the first $x$ least significant bits of both $p$ and $q$ are leaked.

- what is the advantage in factoring $N$?
- Does this give an advantage beyond simply lowering the number of bits we have to guess for the smaller factor?

Comment: Note: the "**_both_** $p$ and $q$" part of the question is pointless: when the low-order $x$ bits $p_{[x]}$ of $p$ leak, we can find the low-order $x$ bits $q_{[x]}$ of $q$ as ${p_{[x]}}^{-1}N\bmod2^x=q_{[x]}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question looked due to the [Cold boot attack](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2009/5/24652-lest-we-remember/abstract), by Halderman et. al. Normally researchers look at some random known bit known due to the decaying of the memory.

- 2009 Heninger et. al [Reconstructing RSA Private Keys from Random Key Bits](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/510.pdf)

  if $\delta = .57$ fraction of the bits of $p$ and $q$ is randomly is given they can construct them.

The closest article is by Maira et. al.

- 2010 - Maitra [Factoring RSA Modulus Using Prime Reconstruction from Random Known Bits](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-12678-9_6), also a [slide](http://2010.africacrypt.com/slides/monday/attacks/SouravSenGupta_Africacrypt2010.pdf) of one of the authors.

  In Section 2 and 3, they look at LSB case. With theorem 1;

**Theorem 1**: Let $N = pq$, when $p, q$ are primes of same bit size. Let $S = \{0,\ldots, l_{N /4}\}$. Consider $U \subseteq S$ and $V = S \backslash U$. Assume that p[i]’s for $i \in U$ and $q[j]$’s for $j \in V$ are known. Then one can factor $N$ in $poly(\log N)$-time.

- $l_N$ the bit size of $N$, i.e, $l_N = \lceil log_2 N\rceil$.